# Interrupt method execution on demand

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods, task

I do have a method for which the execution time might take a while (approx. 2 minutes) running inside a task:

```
public Task BaseWorkerTask { get; set; }

public void Initialize()
{
    BaseWorkerTask = Task.Run(() => 
    {
        BaseWorker();
    });
}

public void BaseWorker()
{
    Server.Speak(Packet.Greeting);

    while (WaitServerResponse())
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
    }

    var response = Server.GetResponse();

    if (response.Equals("abc"))
    {
        DoAbcTask();
    }
    else if (response.Equals("def"))
    {
        [...]
    }

    [...]
}
```

I would like to be able to interrupt it's execution for a given period of time in order to do some other server calls. What is important to note here, is that I want it to "pause" script execution at current line in the `BaseWorker` method, just where it's exactly at.

Something like:

```
if (!BaseWorkerTask.IsCompleted)
{
    // Pause to do something else
    // BaseWorkerTask.StopAtCurrentPlace();

    DoSomethingElse();

    // Once something else is done, resume BaseWorkerTask
    // BaseWorkerTask.Resume();
}
```

Can such approach be achieved?

I have been trying to play with blocking a thread, however I was only able to block it once the method has finished using endless loop with `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(...)`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/threading/thread-synchronization may be of interest.

Comment: Have a look at the `ManualResetEvent` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

[`Thread.Suspend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.suspend?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Threading_Thread_Suspend) is probably the closest you'll get, but it's ***marked as obsolete*** with the following (relevant) warning:

> Do not use the Suspend and Resume methods to synchronize the activities of threads. You have no way of knowing what code a thread is executing when you suspend it. If you suspend a thread while it holds locks during a security permission evaluation, other threads in the AppDomain might be blocked. If you suspend a thread while it is executing a class constructor, other threads in the AppDomain that attempt to use that class are blocked. Deadlocks can occur very easily.

In short, anything that can do this would be a bad idea for exactly the same reasons as above.

Attempting to use it on thread-pool threads virtually assures you of malfunction.

If you want to do this, you'll have to think of a way that the task can co-operate in its own pausing. Likely, this will involve peppering the code with synchronization stuff.

What's taking so long anyway?

Comment: Thanks. `What's taking so long anyway?` Well, I do lots of packet testings around, additionally http requests are being made, all of that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some kind of a `bool` flag, similar to a cancellation token. Set it to `true` when you want to suspend execution of the task, and inside of the `BaseWorker` check the value of the variable at various places. If it's `true`, use `Thread.Sleep` to halt execution until it's set to `false`.

Example:

```
bool suspendExecution = false;

public void Initialize()
{
    BaseWorkerTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        BaseWorker(ref suspendExecution);
    });
}



public void BaseWorker(ref bool suspend)
{
    while (WaitServerResponse())
    {
         if (suspend)
         {
             while (suspend)
             {
                 Thread.Sleep(1000);
             }
         }

         DoSomethingElse();
     }
}
```